# Set Shell Title Property dynamically from code behind

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have implemented shell and I populate its items from code behind. I want to change the title property of items on runtime I am setting the title property from the resource file like this

```
Title = (String) Application.Current.Resources["MAIN_FLYER_SETTING_TEXT"],
```

on run time if resource change title not changing according to that resource. Any help here?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/164313/shell-titleview-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> on run time if resource change title not changing according to that resource.

You're not using data binding so it would never notify the change if the resource  changes .

There are two ways you could choose

1.Set the value every time when Resources get changes.

```
    //resource changes
    Title = (String) Application.Current.Resources["MAIN_FLYER_SETTING_TEXT"]
```

2.Create a viewmodel and property ,implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings) , then create binding on Title .

Comment: thanx @cole for your reply, i'll look into it, just a minor question we achieve this on xaml using dynamic resource, is there a way to call dynamic resource on code behind

Comment: Could you post the code of using dynamic resource ?

Comment: i'm not using dynamic resource on xaml as my shell items are creating on code behind.By the way i try your solution .1 and it works :)

Comment: Click the √ button on left side .